# org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute statement

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

i want to store user feedback into this table

```
CREATE TABLE  SITEWATCHER.HELPREQUESTS (
request_id              int(11)  NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
customer_id             INT(11) forgien key,
issue_type              varchar(50),
phone_number            numeric(10),
issue_description       varchar(256),
date_created            timestamp
);
```

in the model domain my setters and getters

```
@Column(name="PHONE_NUMBER", nullable = false)
private Number phoneNumber; 
 public Number getPhoneNumber() {
    return phoneNumber;
}
public void setPhoneNumber(Number phoneNumber) {
    this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
}
```

and in controller i am parsing phonenumber like this

```
 helprequests.setPhoneNumber(Long.parseLong(phoneNumber.replaceAll( "[^\\d]", "" )));
```

while storing into DB I am getting the following `stacktrace`

```
 May 24 11:34:06 ERROR ne.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions             || Incorrect decimal value: '\xAC\xED\x00\x05sr\x00\x0Ejava.lang.Long;\x8B\xE4\x90\xCC\x8F#\xDF\x02\x00\x01J\x00\x05valuexr\x00\x10java.lang.Number\x86\xAC\x' for column 'phone_number' at row 1
May 24 11:34:06 DEBUG itewatcher.web.LoginController saveUserHelp              || org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute statement
org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:54)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:112)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:190)
    at org.hibernate.id.IdentityGenerator$GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.executeAndExtract(IdentityGenerator.java:96)
    at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:58)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3032)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3556)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:97)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:480)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:191)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:175)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:210)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:324)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:288)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:194)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:125)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:209)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:55)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:194)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:90)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:711)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:703)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:698)
    at com.sitewatcher.dao.impl.CustomerDaoImpl.saveHelp(CustomerDaoImpl.java:156)
    at com.sitewatcher.service.impl.CustomerManagerImpl.saveHelp(CustomerManagerImpl.java:162)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:262)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    at $Proxy759.saveHelp(Unknown Source)
    at com.sitewatcher.web.LoginController.saveUserHelp(LoginController.java:304)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:214)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:748)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:689)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:945)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:876)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:931)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:833)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:807)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter.doFilter(ConcurrentSessionFilter.java:125)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:190)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:92)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.process(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:126)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.invoke(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:70)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:829)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:598)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect decimal value: '\xAC\xED\x00\x05sr\x00\x0Ejava.lang.Long;\x8B\xE4\x90\xCC\x8F#\xDF\x02\x00\x01J\x00\x05valuexr\x00\x10java.lang.Number\x86\xAC\x' for column 'phone_number' at row 1
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1073)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3597)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3529)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1990)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2151)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2625)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2119)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2415)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2333)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2318)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:102)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:187)
    ... 102 more
```

Can any one help me how to resolve it?

Comment: _Please Read First Line of Error for the Answer._ `Number` *AND* `long`

Comment: note: phone_number column should be a string and not numeric, since you're not doing any numeric operation on it

Comment: if i take it as string how it will store into table it is numeric right?

Comment: Instead of Number try with Long. Answer i given below.. try once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the exception properly,

java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619) Caused by: **java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect decimal value:** '\xAC\xED\x00\x05sr\x00\x0E **java.lang.Long** ;\x8B\xE4\x90\xCC\x8F#\xDF\x02\x00\x01J\x00\x05valuexr\x00\x10 **java.lang.Number** \x86\xAC\x' for column 'phone_number' at row 1 at

Instead of **Number** try with **Long** data type like,

```
Column(name="PHONE_NUMBER", nullable = false)
private Long phoneNumber; 
public Long getPhoneNumber() {
    return phoneNumber;
}

public void setPhoneNumber(Long phoneNumber) {
    this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
}
```

Comment: javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.sitewatcher.domain.Helprequests.setPhoneNumber(Ljava/lang/Number;)V

Comment: First check the value is long or not. Long phoneNumber = Long.parseLong(phoneNumber.replaceAll( "[^\\d]", "" ))

Comment: Use your code with following line changes                             Number phoneNumber = Long.parseLong(phoneNumber.replaceAll( "[^\\d]", "" )); helprequests.setPhoneNumber(phoneNumber);

Comment: i tried but May 24 12:39:50 ERROR ne.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions             || Incorrect decimal value: '\xAC\xED\x00\x05sr\x00\x0Ejava.lang.Long;\x8B\xE4\x90\xCC\x8F#\xDF\x02\x00\x01J\x00\x05valuexr\x00\x10java.lang.Number\x86\xAC\x' for column 'phone_number' at row 1
May 24 12:39:50 DEBUG itewatcher.web.LoginController saveUserHelp              || org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute statement
org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute statement

Comment: set length as 10  Column(name="PHONE_NUMBER", nullable = false, length=10)

Comment: In Configuration file add this line <property name="show_sql">true</property> you can see the query how it is constructing.

Comment: i am getting this stack while inserting org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: null id in com.sitewatcher.domain.Helprequests entry (don't flush the Session after an exception occurs)

Comment: Then Check primary key filed and value you are setting properly or not.

Comment: primary key is auto increment no need to set anything

Comment: i deleted all the .class files now With Long it is working fine ThanQ Ranga giving responses to me

Comment: Finally you got the answer. Then like my answer.